# Why the battery need to be loaded before to root?

Tags: rooting, battery

I read in some tutoriel that for the root to be working, battery needed to be loaded around 70 at at least.

Why is it so?
Does it endanger the phone, or it just prevent the root to be working for some reason?

Comment: Simple - if the battery is low, as rooting can be slow depending on handset, and the battery runs out, rooting will fail, but generally, battery must be at least 75% full for *flashing*, not rooting :)

Comment: @t0mm13b is right. Technically there should be no reason that you even need a battery inserted to flash (it's just power, which is already provided by USB here). Some phones however switch off if you remove the battery even if USB power is connected. It would be fatal for those phones if the battery dies before the flash procedure is done. That's why someone imposed the 75% charged battery precaution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a safety factor.  Depending on the exact method, the rooting process can take a hour or more and if you run out of juice in the middle of the process, your phone can wind up bricked.

Comment: not exactly bricked - more likely **soft** bricked...